# Advice on vision ML classifier pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, computer-vision

I'm a neuroscientist and I've become quite good at using ML to predict a variety of variables of interest, however have no experience with vision ML. My aim in 2022-2023 is to learn vision ML so that I can apply it in medical research. However, I'd like to teach myself vision ML first by doing something fun. My idea was to use UFC fighter mugshots in order to see whether I can predict with above chance who will be the fight winner. I've used datasets from Kaggle of fighter statistics to see how well I can predict fight winner and I get 72% accuracy, basically the accuracy I've achieved is in the ballpark of what all other attempts have achieved before me. I'm wondering if in addition to these fighter stats adding some imagery features will up the accuracy.

Any comments, advice and suggestions on what the steps/pipeline I should take to achieve these are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do multi-modal classification?

If yes, the basic principle is to have one model for stats data, one model for image data, and one model that decides which one is more informative.

However, this solution considers photos as important as stats, which might not be the case.

Consequently, a better solution is to include the photos data in your existing data in a compressed way through CNNs like another feature: the result from the fully connected layer would differentiate each picture efficiently thanks to a flattened vector.

As pictures are not as important as all stats, it is better to consider the pictures as a single feature as important as any stat.

Note: Some notebooks have interesting code that reaches 78% accuracy only from stats (see https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mdabbert/ultimate-ufc-dataset/code).